# extending React.Component class

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have recently started working with React and getting understanding of how the framework works,

I have two pieces of code below , just wondering that what's the difference between them (of-course I am not asking about the syntactical differences) and why one of them gives error.

**this one works**

```
interface Square {
  value:String;
}

class Square extends React.Component<Square,{}> {

}
```

**this one gives following error**

> [ts] Generic type 'Component' requires 2 type argument(s).

```
class Square extends React.Component {}
```

I have seen many examples on the net which extend **React.Component** for writing new components, I think I am missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using TypeScript.

The code you saw on the internet `class xxx extends React.Component` is just ES6 code.

Here is a simple React code written in TypeScript:

```
interface SomeProps {
    blabla: string;
}

class SomeComponent extends React.Component<SomeProps, any> {
    constructor(props: SomeProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <h1>{this.props.blabla}</h1>;
    }
}
```